# What is "total" in the output of "ls" command?

Tags: ls

I have an empty directory. I am using following command to view the contents of that directory.

```
ls -lart
```

The output I get is below.

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Oct  2 12:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 apx   aim   4096 Nov 29 18:40 .
```

I don't have any files in this directory, then what counts out to 12 here (`total 12`)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is the total number of blocks taken up by the files, although I would expect the total to be 8 instead of 12 (using 1k blocks).  Try `ls -as1` to see the size in blocks of each file.

Comment: This is the output I get...                                               `total 12
     4 drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Oct  2 12:26 ..
     8 drwxr-xr-x 2 apx   aim   4096 Nov 29 18:40 .`

Answer (score 7):

The "total" is the disk usage of listed files (because of `-a` including the  `.` and `..` entries) in *blocks* (1024 bytes or if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in 512 bytes), not including the content of subdirectories.

If same files are not referenced and therefore listed twice (hard-links), you can get the same output with

```
du -Ss
```

or in human readable units

```
du -Ssh
```

Comment: No, `ls` just adds up the disk usage of the files **listed** (so  `.` and `..` are included only if `-a` is included), and contrary to `du`, `ls` doesn't account for hardlinks, so the result will be different. `-a`, `-A` (GNU), `-L` at least will affect the value reported. Also note that with GNU ls, the value will be different if POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment (block size 512) or not (block size 1024)

Comment: Thanks Stephane Chazelas for your comment. I improved my answer. As GNU's `du` react also on POSIXLY_CORRECT, it should use the same block size.

Answer (score 2):

total count of blocks, it includes also indirect blocks.