# How does Linux calculate the total block count when running /bin/ls -l?

Tags: files, ls, disk-usage, coreutils

I am trying to figure out how the program `/bin/ls -l` calculates the total size (block count) for a directory.
By this I mean the output `total number` that it prints right before the directory contents.

There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l but it doesn't fully answer the question nor explain exactly how it is calculated.

I've tried adding the [numbers of 512B blocks allocated](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)
for all the (non-hidden) files in a directory. 
Here is how I am trying to go about it (in C):

```
 int getBlockSize(char* directory) {
   int size = 0;

   DIR *d;
   struct dirent *dir;
   struct stat fileStat;
   d = opendir(directory);
   if (d) {
       while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
           if (dir->d_name[0] != '.') { // Ignore hidden files
               // Create the path to stat
               char info_path[PATH_MAX + 1];
               strcpy(info_path, directory);
               if (directory[strlen(directory) - 1] != '/')
                   strcat(info_path, "/");
               strcat(info_path, dir->d_name);

               stat(info_path, &fileStat);

               size += fileStat.st_blocks;
           }
       }
   }

   return size;
}
```

However this is giving me a much different number compared to the `ls` command.

What is 'wrong' with my approach?  How does `ls` compute the total?

**Edit:**

To test I made a folder which contains files `test_file1.txt` and `test_file2.txt` each containing the text `Hello World!`. When I run `ls -l` I get the following output

```
total 1
-rw-------. 1 aaa111 ugrad 13 Oct 27 13:17 test_file1.txt
-rw-------. 1 aaa111 ugrad 13 Oct 27 13:17 test_file2.txt
```

However when I run my code using the method above I get

```
total 2
-rw-------. 1 aaa111 ugrad 13 Oct 27 13:17 test_file1.txt
-rw-------. 1 aaa111 ugrad 13 Oct 27 13:17 test_file2.txt
```

Comment: Might be of interest: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n141 (look for uses of that macro in that file)

Comment: Slightly related: [How does `du` count blocks used](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284201/86440).

Comment: Try modifying your program to print each `st_blocks` value (along with the filename) and compare to the output from `ls -l`.  If you can't figure it out from that, then post the outputs (for as small a directory as you can get non-matching results from). Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7401744/2344631

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is total in the output of ls command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57130/what-is-total-in-the-output-of-ls-command)

Comment: On what filesystem did you test this? On what operating system?

Comment: @Gilles ext4 and Ubuntu

Comment: The error made is assuming block size is 512. That is a DOS dinosaur; 'ls' is listing a block size of 1024 instead of 512, and that may change again in the future as *sector* sizes on drives get larger. On GNU 'ls', if you try "ls -l --block-size=512", you will ge the same results as your code.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, the default `ls` is [GNU `ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html), which [defaults to 1024-byte block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html) for its “total” line. This explains the difference in output between `ls` and your approach: your approach shows double the number of blocks because it’s counting 512-byte blocks.

There are various ways to force GNU `ls` to count in 512-byte blocks (see the link above); the most reliable is to set `LS_BLOCK_SIZE`:

```
LS_BLOCK_SIZE=512 ls -l
```

The other implementation of `ls` which you’re liable to run into on Linux is [BusyBox](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=busybox&t=ffab&ia=web) `ls`; it also uses a 1024-byte block size for the “total” line, and it can’t be configured to use any other size.

Comment: While that works with GNU `ls`, that doesn't work with busybox `ls` (probably the most common `ls` implementation on systems that have Linux as their kernel, though not the type of systems people would use an interactive shell on). Note that with GNU `ls`, `$LS_BLOCK_SIZE` takes precedence over `$BLOCKSIZE` which itself takes precedence over `$POSIXLY_CORRECT`.